# Kefir.js - How to stream events from a callback function?

Tags: javascript, frp

The [Mousetrap.js](https://craig.is/killing/mice) library lets you bind a callback function to keys like so:

`Mousetrap.bind('space', function, 'keydown');`

What's the best way to attach a stream to this without using the [Bus of Doom](http://baconjs.blogspot.com/2014/12/bus-of-doom.html)? Should I use `emitter` or `pool`?

I'm trying to get arrow keys hooked up in this fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/vzafq25w](http://jsfiddle.net/vzafq25w)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use general wrapper `stream`

```
var leftKeys = Kefir.stream(function(emitter){
    Mousetrap.bind('left', function(e) {
        emitter.emit(e);
        console.log(e);
    });
    return function(){
        // unbind
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/be9200kh/1/

Comment: This is right way to do it. Also `emitter.emit` can be passed directly as a callback — `Mousetrap.bind('left', emitter.emit)`, unless you need that log of course.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you can use `Kefir.fromEvents`, but in your case, where Mousetrap.js does not bind using `on|off` methods, you can instead just use `Kefir.pool` (`Kefir.emitter` was deprecated) and trigger Kefir in the Mousetrap callbacks. I modified your code to demonstrate using `Kefir.pool` in the Mousetrap callbacks: http://jsfiddle.net/be9200kh/

Basically, you do

```
var pool = Kefir.pool();
pool.plug(Kefir.constant(1));
pool.map(...).filter(etc)
```

Have fun!